# Unable to MergeDex in Android Studio after updating Firebase and Google play services

Tags: java, android, android-studio, merge

The error which I am receiving is this:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>
> > java.lang.RuntimeException:   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
> >     dex

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app.monmos"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner      "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    productFlavors {
    }
    }
    android {
    defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
     }
      }
   dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1'
//Libraries
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
 implementation 'com.cepheuen.elegant-number-button:lib:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.0'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my project build.gradle project:

```
    buildscript {

        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'


            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
 }
 }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have updated the firebase version from **10.2.0** to **12.0.0** and the app is bringing up an error saying telling me to merge dex. I think 2 libraries are clashing.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the following Firebase-UI:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.1'
```

Has a [strict dependencies](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases/tag/3.1.1) of:

- Firebase/Play services version **11.6.2**
- Support Library version **27.0.1**

So, you need change the dependencies according to it.

You can view the documentation in case you need to use the recent supported Firebase/Play service at [Firebase-UI for Android](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android).